# Getting rendered html final source

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing desktop application. I would like to grab remote html source. But remote page widely rendered by javascript after page load.

I'm searching for a few days but i could not find anything useful. I've studied and tried to apply the following suggestions. But I can get only base html codes.

[WebBrowser Threads don't seem to be closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769371/webbrowser-threads-dont-seem-to-be-closing)

[Get the final generated html source using c# or vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847656/get-the-final-generated-html-source-using-c-sharp-or-vb-net)

[View Generated Source (After AJAX/JavaScript) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307800/view-generated-source-after-ajax-javascript-in-c-sharp)

Is there any way to get all data like html console's approach of firebug?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any results?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  A web browser will do more than just grab the HTML. It needs to be parsed (which will likely download further files) and rendered. You could use the WebKit C# wrapper  [[http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/]](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) - I have used this previously to get thumbnails of web pages.

Comment: For example html initial source like <div id="foo"></div> but this div fills data with javascript onPageLoad event. When grabs page with using WebClient results seems like <div id="foo"></div> I would like to get html's div with filled data.

Comment: So you want to tap into the browsers rendering engine. The only other HTML / C# thing I have come across that 'may' be of use is http://www.awesomium.com/